# How do I construct a std::string with a variable number of spaces?

Tags: c++

If I have the following code:

```
std::string name =   "Michael";
std::string spaces = "       ";
```

How would I programatically create the `spaces` string (a string with all spaces, the length matching the name variable)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can pass a character and a length to a string, and it will fill a string of that length with the given character:

```
std::string spaces(7, ' ');
```

You can use the `.size()` property of std::string to find the length of your name; combined with the above:

```
std::string name = "Michael";
std::string spaces(name.size(), ' ');
```

Answer (score 9):

from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/

```
std::string spaces(name.length(), ' ');
```

Comment: Note: I would use `size()` instead of `length()` because `size()` matches the STL containers (will make your code more consistent). +1 though.

Answer (score 6):

```
std::string spaces(name.size(), ' ');
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you know the length of 'name', hereby refered to as nameLength

```
std::string spaces(nameLength,' ');
```